# how to run .java file or execute a java application in iphone simulator?

Tags: java, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an application made in java.I have .jar and also the complete source of the project.I want to use it's classes in xcode means i want to use function in objective-c without converting them.Or is there a way to execute the whole app in iphone simulator or device.please tell me step by step.I have SDK 3.0 and xcode 3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

I doubt whether Apple allows third party run-times (virtual machines) to run on iPhone. Therefore you may not be able to use / link any JVM based classes.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a JVM on the iPhone; you'll need to write native code.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_OS#Java) says that it may be possible on jailbroken devices.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Java is not available as a jvm does not comply with the Apple license terms.

There is a commercial product for Mono which allows you to program the iPhone in C# (it compiles to native code).